# Salesforce's APEX language specification

Tags: salesforce, apex-code, force.com, specifications, apex

I'd like to find out exact APEX language specification (with all that grammars, etc.) but I've spent half a day and ended with almost nothing.

I know that APEX is Java-based language, but compiling it's spec on my own from Java spec and exclusively APEX things will be a pain.

Is there any place where I can get APEX language specification?

For those not familiar with them - I'm looking for a such document http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/index.html for it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is that Salesforce haven't currently published such a document. Instead they want you to use the Tooling API to get the tokens etc...

See [Grammar for creating an Apex parser](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/1003/grammar-for-creating-an-apex-parser)

Depending on your scenario you might find the [Apex Language Server](https://developer.salesforce.com/tools/vscode/en/apex/language-server/) a useful tool. It does the Apex parsing etc... behind the scenes for the current VSCode tooling.

---

Incidentally, the [Salesforce StackExchange site](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com) linked above is a great place to ask Salesforce specific questions.

Answer (score -1):

Actually, Salesforce does publish a detailed Apex developer guide.

**The current 2017 document can be found [here](https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/208/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_apex_language_reference.pdf)** :

https://resources.docs.salesforce.com/208/latest/en-us/sfdc/pdf/salesforce_apex_language_reference.pdf

This document and it's location could be updated frequently, so you can also Google 'Apex Developer Guide' to get [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dev_guide.htm) :

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_dev_guide.htm

Once here, click the PDF button to generate/view the latest PDF, or use the available content options to view online.

[image]